# What does the (2) mean in the below SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

Someone please explain why that `2` is used in the below query.

```
select * from employee e 
where(2) = (select count(distinct(e1.sal))
            from employee e1
            where e.sal > e1.sal);
```

Comment: meaning you are expecting 2 distinct salary from whole employee with your co-relation query.

Comment: Usually conditionals are written as `WHERE some_condition = 5`, but you can also write it in reverse: `WHERE 5 = some_condition`.

Comment: same as `where (select ...) = 2` The parentheses around the `2` are useless.

Comment: So in this case you are selecting the person with the third from lowest salary, i.e there are 2 other employee salary values that are lower than his/hers.

Comment: (I should have said "employee(s)" rather than "person" as there could be more than one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query returns all employees whose Salary is higher than **2** other salaries.  The parentheses is misleading and isn't needed.

```
select * from employee e 
where 2 = (select count(distinct(e1.sal))
            from employee e1
            where e.sal > e1.sal);
```

For example, given the follow employees data:

```
      Employee  Salary  Count     Greater than
                       (Distinct) these Salaries
       Joe     $80,000     0      Lowest Salary
       Kate    $80,000     0      Lowest Salary
       Lee     $85,000     1      $80,000
       Chris   $85,000     1      $80,000
       Matt    $85,000     1      $80,000
       Mike    $90,000     2      $85,000,$80,000
       June    $90,000     2      $85,000,$80,000     
       Jack    $100,000    3      $90,000,$85,000,$80,000
```

```
 The query returns
```

```
       Mike    $90,000
       June    $90,000
```

```
  because 90,000 is greater than 80,000 and 85,000

 Notice that Jack is not returned because his salary is greater than 3 other salaries.  Also note there are 5 employees with a salary less than Mike's and June's but the distinct keyword forces the count to 2.
```

Comment: Can you explain flow-wise  how we come up with this solution?

Comment: I added two columns to help with the flow.  First get a list of distinct salaries: 80,85,90, and 100.  Then look at each employee and list which salaries his salary is greater than.  Mike's salary is greater than 80 and 85.  Count them.  Mike's count is 2.  Then return all employees whose count is 2 according to the left side of the =.

Answer (score 0):

As noted parentheses around the number 2 are useless. Equivalent query could be

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  select sal, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY sal) dr from employee
) emp
WHERE emp.dr = 3
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1c187/4)

As you can see in the example, you are searching for employees where two different lower salaries exist in the employees table.